# Suddenly clip-path stop working on my site, it was working fine few days ago

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

if you visit here http://www.sseasports.com/ and check at bottom of site the "Factory View" section, 
i create gallery there using clip-path polygon it was working fine few days ago but i don't know what happened and now it's not working,

haven't change or update anything

i already try this

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
```

i also use -webkit prefix but still not working,

please have a look and reply

Thanks

Comment: add `overflow: hidden;` to the element with clip path

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score -1):

Add the clip-path directly to `<img>`